# Current sensor and ADC with different ranges

Tags: adc, current-measurement

Is it possible to have this [Current sensor](https://www.digikey.no/product-detail/en/allegro-microsystems-llc/ACS711ELCTR-25AB-T/620-1371-1-ND/2470595), with ranges from 0-7V out, to this [ADC](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/ADS7961QDBTRQ1/296-39870-6-ND/5178980), whitch have a voltage range of 0-5V (0 - 2xVref), and just use a voltage divider inbetween to change the voltage out of the Current sensor down to 0-5V

Since the output from the current sensor is analog is it going te be any problems solving this issue this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have looked at the absolute maximum ratings in the data sheet AND you have wrongly concluded that the output ranges from 0 to 7 volts. Commonly, this device operates from a supply between 3.0 volts and 5.5 volts so it won't produce 7 volts unless you are overstressing it. Don't do that.

The output voltage is nominally half Vcc and rises positively or negatively depending on the direction of the current. Saturation limits are 0.3 volts inside the power rails hence, on a 5 volts supply, you can expect a negative to positive output range of 0.3 volts to 4.7 volts.

Read the data sheet.